# How to remember url?

Tags: php, html, variables, url

So I'm passing variables in the url like this:

First select menu

```
<select  name="car_id" onchange="location='newcar/'+this.value" >
        <option>-</option>
        <?php foreach ($cars as $car) {             
                if (isset($car->id)) {
                    echo "<option value=\"" . $car->id  .  "\">";
                    echo $car->car . "</option>\n";
                }
        } ?>
        </select>
```

So if i press one of the options it will store it's value on the url. But then I have another select menu that shows the models and the problem is that the url isn't showing right.
    
    I don't know what I should write on the onchange that the first select menu's variable would be there to.

I want my url to show `www.example.com/newcar/2/3` but this far i can get is `www.example.com/newcar/2` and then the number 3 replaces number 2.

Comment: Show code for both selects (and their JS), just one of them does not give us the whole picture. Is the URL supposed to be `/newcar/{firstSelectValue}/{secondSelectValue}`?

Comment: Also, don't show PHP code when it is not relevant. Always try to reduce your problem to manageable parts. Usually, unless your question is about PHP, you should show the generated (abbreviated) HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a single function to respond to changes to both `select`

```js
(window.onSelectChange = function() {
    var val1 = document.getElementById('sel1').value;
    var val2 = document.getElementById('sel2').value;
    document.getElementById('url').value = 'http://example.com/something/' + val1 + '/' + val2;
})()
```

```css
input {width: 100%}
```

```html
<select id="sel1" onchange="onSelectChange()">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id="sel2" onchange="onSelectChange()">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>

<hr />
URL: <input id='url' />
```

Note that the above does not show "best practices", I was trying to keep it as close to your code as possible.